# Keeping tracks of the first digit of similar items in a list Python

Tags: python-3.x

For example,
lst = ['120 abc','123 abc','256 abc','125 bcd','326 bcd','426 bcd']

I want to count how many time 2 is the second digit in each item.

In the lst above:

2 occurs 2 times for items ending in abc
2 occurs 3 times for itmes ending in bcd

My question is related to an assignment on Benford's law. The text file given is structured similar to the lst above.  The numbers represent ballots count and the letters represent name of cities.

My program reads the file and put each ballots count and the corresponding city as an item in a list.

Since each item in the list is a string, i know to to index through each item for the desired digit, and count the number of occurrences. But i don't know how to separate each item into similar group of items.

I'm an absolute beginner to programming.  I'm not looking for actual codes but ideas on how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to just itterate the list and when you find an index that matches more then once just add to it's place in the list. This snippet should give you the idea of how it is done.

```
lst = ['120 abc','123 abc','256 abc','125 bcd','326 bcd','426 bcd']
list2 = {}
for listItem in lst:
    if listItem.index('2') == 1:
        t = listItem.split()        
        if t[1] in list2:
            list2[t[1]] = list2[t[1]] + 1
        else:
            list2[t[1]] = 1

print(list2)
```

listItem.split() is a standard function that divides the string on a whitespace, after that we can use "abc" as a key and place the value in a dictionary and sum up the number of times that any particular string occured.

Comment: This is more what i had in mind.  The assignment also included a text file with many items with many different names. Your approach using a dictionary makes it easier to manage the data retrieved from the text file. Thanks a lot for the ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing helps you to rapidly retrieve an element of a sequence. First item has always the zero index. Both list and string are sequences, so:

```
>>> lst[2]
'256 abc'
>>> lst[2][1]
'5'
```

With the knowledge of indexing you can easily get all the second characters of a list in a new list with a generator expression:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in lst]
['2', '2', '5', '2', '2', '2']
```

Now you only have to count the twos there:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in lst].count('2')
5
```

If you only want those which ends witha a specific string, use this genexp:

```
>>> [x[1] for x in lst if x.endswith('abc')]
['2', '2', '5']
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. This is my first programming class. Up until now, i'd never have thought to code using the for and if statements the way you've demonstrated[x[1] for x in lst if x.endswith('abc')]. I only use 'for' to iterate and 'if' to select conditions...For statement follows by ":" and then 'if' and 'elif' suites.